# i'm getting expected output only but while i'm submitting in code chef I'm getting run time error message

Tags: c++, string

**CodeChef problem:** Forgotten languages (also known as extinct languages) are languages that are no longer in use. Such languages were, probably, widely used before and no one could have ever imagined that they will become extinct at some point. Unfortunately, that is what happened to them. On the happy side of things, a language may be dead, but some of its words may continue to be used in other languages.

Using something called as the Internet, you have acquired a dictionary of N words of a forgotten language. Meanwhile, you also know K phrases used in modern languages. For each of the words of the forgotten language, your task is to determine whether the word is still in use in any of these K modern phrases or not.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of a test case description contains two space separated positive integers N and K.

The second line of the description contains N strings denoting a dictionary of the forgotten language.

Each of the next K lines of the description starts with one positive integer L denoting the number of words in the corresponding phrase in modern languages. The integer is followed by L strings (not necessarily distinct) denoting the phrase.

**Output**

For each test case, output a single line containing N tokens (space-separated): if the ith word of the dictionary exists in at least one phrase in modern languages, then you should output YES as the ith token, otherwise NO.

**Constraints**

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 20
1 ≤ N ≤ 100
1 ≤ K, L ≤ 50
1 ≤ length of any string in the input ≤ 5
```

**My code is: (C++ language)**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string forgot[109],modern[55];
    int N,K,count=0,T;
    cin>>T;
    for(int x=0;x<T;x++){
        cin>>N >>K;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) 
            cin>>forgot[i];
        for(int i=0;i<K;i++){
            int M;
            cin>>M;
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                cin>>modern[count];
                count++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            int l=0;
            for(int j=0;j<count;j++){;
                if(forgot[i]==modern[j]) {
                    l++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(l!=0) cout<<"YES ";
            else cout<<"NO ";
        } 
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

My code is running on local machine as expected while i'm submitting in the codechef portal i'm getting runtime error message. Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks

please find the below sample input and output for the problem

**Example**

Input:

```
 2
 3 2
 piygu ezyfo rzotm
 1 piygu
 6 tefwz tefwz piygu ezyfo tefwz piygu
 4 1
 kssdy tjzhy ljzym kegqz
 4 kegqz kegqz kegqz vxvyj
```

**Output:**

```
 YES YES NO 
 NO NO NO YES
```

Comment: You could reveal the "runtime error message"

Comment: You should protect your code against wrong input: N=200 will make your code to crash.

Comment: codechef has an individual forum to discuss. I think it is better suit there.

Comment: thanks for editing my code@Adrian Maire. they mention constraint as N should be a less than 100 so for all test cases N<=100

Comment: @StillLearning they mention it as runtime error only but they didn't tell any thing else but my point of view most of runtime errors occur because of more memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems.

1) The variable `count` is only set to zero once. Hereafter it is just incremented and will so sooner or later be over 54 and the program will crash.

2) Your code will require the `modern`array to have the size `K * L`. You can't do that as there is no limit for `K`. So the loop checking for matches must be inside the K-loop (instead of outside). Perhaps you could make an array with results and then update that array inside the loop.

Something like:

```
int main(){
    string forgot[109],modern[55];
    bool matched[109];
    int N,K,T;
    cin>>T;
    for(int x=0;x<T;x++){
        cin>>N >>K;

        // Read forgotten words
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            cin>>forgot[i];
            matched[i] = false;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<K;i++){
            int M;
            cin>>M;
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                cin>>modern[j];
            }

            // Compare this line with forgotten words
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                    if(forgot[i]==modern[j]) {
                        matched[i] = true;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        // Done with test case - print result
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            if (matched[i])
            {
                cout << "YES ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "NO  ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response@StillLearning. Based on your comments i tried but still I'm getting run time error message (Run time Error(SIGSEGV)).

Comment: based on your code. we will get below output.                                        YES NO NO 
YES YES NO 
NO NO NO YES

Comment: thanks for your answer. your answer is really helpfull for me